# Know if JRE is 32 or 64 bit from Windows Command Promt

Tags: java, windows, 32bit-64bit

I want to know if there is a way to determine, from the Windows Command Prompt, if the JRE is 32 or 64 Bit.
I want to use it in a Windows Script to modifiy the java.library.path, because I use DLLs in 32 or 64 bits. So, I want to launch my Java Program with "java -cp blabla -Djava.library.path=bin/x64" with a 64 bits JRE and launch it with "java -cp blabla -Djava.library.path=bin/x86" with a 32 bits JRE. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance,
Cédric

Comment: run `java -version` in command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line wizards may find a smaller solution but this works:

```
 java -version 2>javaversion.tmp
 set JAVA_VERSION=
 for /F "usebackq" %%A in (`findstr /C:"64-Bit" javaversion.tmp`) do set JAVA_VERSION=64
 if %JAVA_VERSION%.==. set JAVA_VERSION=32
 del javaversion.tmp
```

It dumps the `java -version`output to a temporary file and then searches if that file contains the string "64". If this is the case it sets the environment variable `JAVA_VERSION` to `64`, else it is set to `32`.

Of course you can adapt this script to setup a `JAVA_LIBPATH` variable instead.

Comment: I think it might fail if the version number happens to contain a 64, e.g., if you had the 32-bit version of 8u64 installed.  Probably better to include a suitable prefix and/or suffix in the search string.

Comment: @HarryJohnston good idea, changed the search string to "64-Bit"